# codemirror show hints with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, codemirror, ui-codemirror

How to show hints and define dictionary with ui-codemirror?

```
       $scope.cmOption = {
        lineWrapping : true,
        lineNumbers: true,
        textWrapping: true,
        indentWithTabs: true,
        readOnly: false,
        mode: "javascript",
        matchBrackets: true,
        autoCloseBrackets: true,
        gutters: ["CodeMirror-lint-markers"],
        lint: true,
        showHint: true
    };
```

I tried with ng-codemirror-dictionary-hint but it gives me an error

> instance.showHint is not a function